# Selectively editing strings based on rules in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, string-decoding

I am trying to develop a rules based string editing function in Matlab.

Suppose I have generated a string like the following:

```
myString = '/+*43/*/+34/5*2/*'
```

Supposed further that I wish to remove certain math operators according to a set of rules:

1. A string cannot start with the '*' or '/' operators
2. A string cannot end with any operator
3. Any sequential operators are replaced by the first operator in that sequence      unless it violates 1 and 2.

So for example the above string would reduce to:

```
myNewString = '+43/34/5*2'
```

Any method is fine to solve this problem, but a vectorized Boolean method would be preferred.

What I would like to do with this string is be able to perform a str2num on it and have it return a value and not throw errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Regular expressions would probably be a good avenue to explore.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can be used here:

```
myString = '/*+*43/*/+34/5*2/*';
myString = regexprep(myString,'^[/*]+','');   % accomplish the rule #1
myString = regexprep(myString,'[/*+-]+$','');   % accomplish the rule #2
myString = regexprep(myString,'[/*+-]{2,}','${$0(1)}')   % accomplish the rule #3
```

Comment: Thank you!
That is elegant.

I was trying to use regular expressions as suggested by excaza in a rather hack method with while loops and empty set replacement, but this is much more simple. 
Seems like there is lots to learn in regular expressions!